# Prove that the given function is bounded, but not continuous, on the the given region

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Let , $$f(z)=\begin{cases}e^{(−1/z)} & \text{ if } z\not=0\\0 & \text{ if }z=0\end{cases}$$
>
> prove that the function is bounded, but not continuous, on the half circle $0\le|z| \le1, |Arg z|\le\pi/2$

**Part 2:** Prove that the function is continuous, but not uniformly, in the interior of this half-circle;
**Part 3:** Prove for every fixed positive $\alpha$ (however close to $\pi/2$), the function is uniformly continuous in the sector $0\lt|z|\le1, |Arg(z)|\le \alpha\lt\pi/2$

We are to assume that every point of a set $\Omega \subset \mathbb C$ is an accumulation point of $\Omega$. We say that $f(z)$ is uniformly continuous on $\Omega$ if for every $a\in \Omega$ and for every $\epsilon\gt0$ there is a $\delta\gt0$ indepent of $a$ such that $|f(z)-f(a)|\lt\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|\lt\delta$

Comment: Hint: Recall that $|e^w|=e^{\text{Re}w}$ and that $\lim_{x\to 0} e^{i/x}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: I think I have the first part, and i think i can show that the function is continuous, but i am not sure how to show that it is not uniform in the half-circle's interior. This is also a big problem i am having with the third part

Comment: If it were unif. cont. in the half circle it would extend to a continuous function in the closed half circle...

Answer (score 0):

For the third part: let $z=r\,e^{i\theta}$ with $0<r\le1$ and $|\theta|\le\alpha<\pi/2$. Then
$$
\big|e^{-1/z}\bigr|=\big|e^{\tfrac{\cos\theta-i\sin\theta}{r}}\bigr|=\big|e^{\tfrac{\cos\theta}{r}}\bigr|\le\big|e^{\tfrac{\cos\alpha}{r}}\bigr|
$$
with $\cos\alpha>0$.
It follows that
$$
\lim_{\substack{z\to0 \\ |\text{Arg}(z)|\le\alpha}}e^{-1/z}=0.
$$

We can reuse the above calculation to show that $e^{-1/z}$ is not uniformly continuous on the open half disk. Let $0<\theta_n<\pi/2$ be such that $\theta_n\to\pi/2$ and $z_n=\cos\theta_ne^{i\theta_n}$. Then $z_n$ is in the open half disk, $z_n\to0$ but $\bigl|e^{-1/z_n}\bigr|=1/e$ for all $n$.