# Is this complex function continuous in the given domain?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let the function $\omega = e^{\frac{-1}{z}}$ be determined with $z\neq 0$.
> Prove that: In the domain $0<|z|\leq 1,|\arg z|\leq\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, $\omega$ is bounded but not uniformly continuous.

My attempt:
Let $z=re^{i\theta}$. Then $\left\vert e^{\frac{-1}{z}}\right\vert=\left\vert e^{\frac{-\cos\theta}{r}}\right\vert\leq 1\Rightarrow f$ is bounded. I don't know how to prove $f$ isn't continuous on the given domain. Can anyone give me some hints?
Also, I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140101/prove-that-the-given-function-is-bounded-but-not-continuous-on-the-the-given-r) ,but it seems not helpful

Comment: Your function, as you put it, is continuous. You have to give it the value $0$ at $z=0$. Then, you can argue for discontinuity

Comment: but does it has its value at $z=0$ to assure its continuity?

Comment: @HyperbolicPDEfriend $z=0$ isn't in the given domain

Comment: I edited the problem

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is continuous and on any compact subset of the set above it is uniformly continuous by general topology; so to disprove uniform continuity, you need to find $x_n, y_n \to 0$ (hence $x_n-y_n \to 0$) st $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|$ does not converge to zero; so for example take $x_n=i/n, y_n=-i/n$ so $f(x_n)=e^{-n/i}, f(y_n)=e^{n/i}$ so $f(x_n)-f(y_n)=e^{-ni}(\cos 2n + i \sin 2n -1)$

Hence $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=2 \sin n$ and the usual arguments ($n/\pi$ mod $1$ is uniformly distributed or even simpler if $\sin n \to 0$ then $\cos 2n =1-2\sin^2 n \to 1$, but then $\sin (2n+1)=\sin 2n \cos 1+\cos 2n \sin 1$ converges on one hand to zero as $2n+1$ is a sub-sequence of $n$ and on the other hand to $\sin 1 \ne 0$ by the above, so contradiction) shows that $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|$ doesn't converge to zero, hence $f$ is not uniformly continuous on the given set.